# What is the pad-etching process in standard CMOS fabrication process

Tags: cmos, etching, fabrication, microfabrication

What is the pad etching process?
Is it possible to etch to the bottom metal layers or vias in standard CMOS fabrication?

Comment: This is a question that should be answered by the design kit you get from your fab vendor.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate [Link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/470740/unusual-etching-in-cmos-technologies)